# generate video with PyAv (from image generator and audio file)

Tags: python, numpy, audio, video, pyav

There is a logic based on the python generator that uses PyAv to create a fixed sound file and an image equal to the length or 1 frame longer.
However, I want to perform this process at once, and I want to implement it without calling ffmpeg additionally.

I know about demuxing sound and video files and muxing them via PyAv, but I can't save the video copy of the file I'm trying to convert with the final product due to insufficient system storage space.

So, how mux audio packet and video frame?

```
import av
import numpy as np

def video_generator(config):
    for _ in range( int(<audio time by second> * config.fps)):
        yield np.zeros((config.height, config.width, 3), dtype = np.uint8)

output = av.open(config.output_file, 'w')
ovstream = output.add_stream('libx264rgb', config.fps)
ovstream.pix_fmt = 'rgb24'
ovstream.width = config.width
ovstream.height = config.height

audio_input = av.open(<input wav>, 'r')
oastream = output.add_stream('mp3')

v_frames = (av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(img, format='rgb24') for img in video_generator(config))
v_frames = (ovstream.encode(frame) for frame in v_frames)

for img_packet in v_frames:
    output.mux(img_packet)
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
...
for img_packet in v_frames:
    output.mux(img_packet)

stream = audio_input.streams.audio[0]
for packet in audio_input.demux((stream,)):
    for frame in packet.decode():
        a_frames = oastream.encode(frame)
        output.mux(a_frames)
output.close()
...
```

Also, if frame drops occur, Adding `output.mux(ovstream.encode()); output.mux(oastream.encode())` right before `output.close()`

https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/issues/597#issuecomment-575349451